# Rails app not loading new environment variable added to /etc/environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, passenger

I'm trying to add an environment variable to use in my Rails App. Currently, our app uses several environment variables defined in `/etc/environment`. They work fine. So I've added a new variable to `/etc/environment` (and rebooted for the hell of it). But when I try to access the new variable, its undefined. Printing out `ENV.inspect` shows all the original variables, but not my newly added one.  Why oh why?

Running Apache 2 / Passenger 4 / Rails 4. Recently upgraded from Passenger 2 / Rails 3 if its significant.

**Edit**

Turns out the ones I thought 'work fine' don't work either (they're redefined in my Rails app). So none of the variables in `/etc/environment` are loaded into the app. Not sure why I thought that system worked, but it doesn't.

Comment: Please expand a bit on "they work fine" - in what way / how do you know?  Also please show at least some of the existing contents of `/etc/environment` and also that is a system directory, not under a web root so not sure how it would work.  Finally please show the _actual_ variable you are trying to add and use.  It's always possible its a reserved word or something like that.  Adding all this will help you get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, will expand on my question.

Comment: Well, in the process of verifying why I thought 'they work fine', I discovered they don't work fine, as per my edit above. If you want to add an answer that says something like _that shouldn't work_ I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Might not be good news to you, but you have to [reboot the instance](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting) to see it happen (or check the other tricks at that question).

You can also use `SetEnv` at your Apache config and just restarting apache itself will make your app see the new values.

Comment: Did reboot the instance. Thanks for the alternative using SetEnv -- at the moment I'd like to figure out why this isn't working rather than use a new solution (though it might be a better one anyways :P).

Answer (score 1):

**ENV**

Upgrading from Rails 3 - Rails 4 should not be a major concern for the `ENV` variables, unless the way Rails processes them will have changed.

We use the following:

[image]

This works for us with Rails 4, Ubuntu 12.04, Passenger, Apache 2

--

The problem you *may* have is that your Rails application has not updated since you added the new variables.

When you run a Rails app, it essentially loads an "instance" of the application, and then keeps loading it somehow. I'm not totally sure how it works, but I *do* know the likes of `Passenger` essentially "cache" a rails app whilst in production

This means if you're adding new Environment variables, perhaps the likes of `Passenger` has made it so the Rails application has not been updated? If this is the case you may wish to [use the `touch tmp/restart.txt` command](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application):

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above I rebooted the server, which would reboot apache, passenger and rails, to no avail. And as per my edit above, it turns out Apache / Passenger / Rails apps won't even load the ENV variables stored in /etc/environment at all.

Comment: Hummmm - are you just using the standard apache user account to run the Rails app?